# Complete separation - how to impose 'zero-mean Normal priors on fixed effects' in bglmer

Tags: r, mixed-models

My `glmer` model, which contains two predictors and an interaction term, suffers from complete separation. Following Ben Bolker's recommendations [here](https://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html) and [here](https://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/ecostats_chap.html#digression-complete-separation), I then fit the model with `bglmer`, imposing zero-mean Normal priors on the fixed effects. My code is as follows:

```
bglmer(Binary_outcome ~ (1|Subject) + Factor1 + Factor2 + Factor1:Factor2, 
       mydata, 
       control=glmerControl(optimizer="bobyqa"), 
       family = binomial, 
       fixef.prior = normal(sd = c(3, 3, 3)))
```

Both Factor1 and Factor2 are factor variables, with four levels each. For my code, I followed the example [here](https://github.com/vdorie/blme/issues/8). As far as I understand, I now put zero-mean Normal priors with SD of 3 on all elements of my fixed effects structure.

The code seems to have worked, but I am completely uncertain whether what I did is in fact correct. Is 3 SD the general recommendation to help with complete separation? And how would I specify `fixef.priors` that only go on the interaction term? (The complete separation relates to a specific combination of `Factor1` and `Factor2`, not `Factor1` or `Factor2` in general). Or do I have to put fixed effect priors on all three elements anyways if the interaction is concerned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When in doubt, experiment. **tl;dr** it's probably fine to penalize everything, but you can if you like penalize the interactions and not penalize the main effects (or almost; you have to give a finite sd but it can be very large). sd=3 is reasonable; sd=2.5 is the default for parameters other than the intercept. Unless you're fitting a predictive model and want to go to the trouble of doing cross-validation to pick the optimal strength of penalization, there's not really an automatic way to decide; you just have to pick a sd that makes all your parameters "reasonable" without squashing your well-determined parameters too much toward zero.

I simulated data a bit like yours (2 factors with 4 levels each, binary response, one random intercept term) and tried different penalization scenarios. I set up the true parameters so that most parameters were reasonable (beta=1) but there was one large main effect and one large interaction parameter (beta=12).

- no penalization (`glmer`)
- penalization with `sd=3`
- penalization of all terms with `sd=1`
- very weak penalization of main effect terms (`sd=1e4`) and medium penalization of interactions (`sd=2`) ["mixed"]

from `help("bmerDist-class")`:

> When specifying standard
> deviations, a vector of length less than the number of fixed
> effects will have its tail repeated, while the first element
> is assumed to apply only to the intercept term. So in the
> default of ‘c(10, 2.5)’, the intercept receives a standard
> deviation of 10 and the various slopes are all given a
> standard deviation of 2.5

### [image]

```
library(lme4)
library(blme)
library(broom.mixed)
library(dotwhisker)
library(colorspace)

dd <- expand.grid(Subject=factor(1:10),
                  Factor1=letters[1:4],
                  Factor2=LETTERS[1:4],
                  rep=1:20
                  )
bvec <- rep(1,16)
bvec[c(2,10)] <- 12
form <- response ~ (1|Subject) + Factor1 + Factor2 + Factor1:Factor2
set.seed(101)
dd$response <- simulate(form[-2],
         newdata=dd,
         newparams=list(beta=bvec, theta=1),
         family=binomial,
         weights=rep(1,nrow(dd)))[[1]]

b0 <- glmer(form, 
            dd,
            family = binomial)
bfun <- function(sd) {
   bglmer(form, dd, family = binomial, fixef.prior = normal(sd = sd))
}
b1 <- bfun(3)
b2 <- bfun(1)
## eight intercept + main effects first, then eight interaction parameters
b3 <- bfun(rep(c(1e4,2),c(8,8))

theme_set(theme_bw())
dwplot(list(unpenalized=b0,sd3=b1,sd1=b2,mixed=b3),effect="fixed") +
    coord_cartesian(xlim=c(-5,5))+
    geom_vline(xintercept=c(0,1),lty=2,colour="darkgray") +
    scale_colour_discrete_qualitative(guide=guide_legend(reverse=TRUE))
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this has been very helpful! I tried all 3 versions, and each of them made the relevant parameter reasonable.

Comment: if this answer solves your problem you are encouraged to click the check-mark to accept it ...

Comment: Done - sorry, I'm still new to the system here!